# How can update a Laravel language file with a function or a query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6, laravel-7

*Hello, I created a Helper function for the laravel localization which store the translates in the Database. and also the function get the translate from the Database. this is the function.*

```
public static function translate($word,$locale) {
    $find_word = DB::table('translate')->where('word', $word);
    if($find_word->count() > 0){
        if(count(DB::table('languages')->where('field_name',$locale)->get()) == 0){
            $locale = 'en';
        }
        if($find_word->first()->$locale !== null  && $find_word->first()->$locale !== ''){
            $return = $find_word->first()->$locale;
        }
        else{
            $return = $find_word->first()->en;
        }
    }
    else{
        $data['word'] = $word;
        $data['en'] = str_replace('_', ' ', $word);
        DB::table('translate')->insert($data);
        $return = str_replace('_', ' ', $word);
        $locale = 'en';
    }
    return $return;
}
```

*The function works correctly but for every word I need to run a Database query. So its better to create such function to save the words in a file not to the database. when I call the function and request a word and the word does not exists add the word to the file. I prefer this function from laravel default localization. because in the Laravel localization we must create a file manually then we must add words and its translate to the file manually.*

So, How can I create such function to save the new requested word in a file or get it from the file?

Comment: You will have to be careful in that you could spend some time writing this and find the advantages are minimal (if they exist at all).  BUT have you done anything yourself so far to try this - your last sentence sounds almost as though you want someone to provide you with a solution.

Comment: I searched for a solution I found this https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/editing-language-files-via-an-admin-panel but I want to see there is a better solutions?

Comment: You said if I find a solution the advantages are minimal. so you say I use the above function? I think it take time to see the Database for every word

Comment: @NigelRen Are you there?

Comment: Sorry - been busy.  The difference is between searching a text file and a database.  Both may include some form of optimization and both include  a certain amount of I/O.  The difference depends on a lot of things and can sometimes be less than you expect, especially when you have a lot of translations in a text file.  Unless you have found something that shows it is quicker with a text file, then the only way you can get a better idea is to try it.

Comment: Ok thanks.also I am waiting for another friends answer.